# How to add text into rowspan in the middle of the table

Tags: html, html-table, row

Can someone please tell me how, to insert data in a row? I just want to write something in these 2 rows:
The red + are the cells in which i want to insert text. I tried many things but it always ended up
building a new line. I would appreciate help :)
[image]

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML rowspan Attribute</title>
        <style>
            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 6px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body style = "text-align:center">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Ajay</td>
                <TD ROWSPAN="3">Bild1</TD> 
                <TD>Bananas</TD>
                
                <TD ROWSPAN="3">Bild2</TD>
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>Priya1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Priya</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add data in second and third row, so you need to enter those data in second and third `<tr>` itself.

Here it is

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Ajay</td>
        <td ROWSPAN="3">Bild1</td> 
        <td>Bananas</td>
        <td ROWSPAN="3">Bild2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Priya1</td>
        <td>Bananas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Priya</td>
        <td>Bananas</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```